# Sequentially timed events using Python/Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I need to develop a simple interface for Stroop test using Python, but I don't know how to start it in Python.

The interface would be like:

10 seconds in a blank screen, the 10 seconds with a colored word on the center of the screen. This would repeat like 10 times, then finish the application.

The problem is: I don't know if I have to use Tkinter + anothe lib (timed events), or if Tkinter provides the methods to use timed events.

Could anyone enlight me,please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timed events can be handled in tkinter with `root.after`, and the number of reps using a parameter, and a test on the value of this parameter.

here is a short example that shows a text label alternatively on a simple window:

```
import tkinter as tk

def toggle_screen(idx=10):
    variable.set(text_values[idx%2])
    if idx > 0:
        root.after(1000, toggle_screen, idx-1)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
text_values = ['', 'hello']

variable = tk.StringVar()
variable.set('')
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=variable, fg='red')
label.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
toggle_screen()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)